# Adding an url parameter to a variable in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

Im trying to add an url parameter to a variable in JSTL like this:

```
<c:set var="stageStandingTeam" value="team.stageStanding.stage${param.stage}"/>
<c:forEach var="team" items="${teams}">
    <c:set var="nr" value="${nr + 1}" scope="page"/>    
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${nr}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${team.user.sirname}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${requestScope[stageStandingTeam]}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${team.stageStanding.stage1}"></c:out></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

When the url is `?stage=1` I expect that the output would be the same as in the last table column, but it's empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you expect that setting 'stageStandingTeam' param to value 'team.stageStanding.stage1' will have some effect on expression '${team.stageStanding.stage1}'?

Comment: No, I would like to output the value of team.stageStanding.stage1 which is set in the controller. so i expect the same result with ${requestScope[stageStandingTeam]} as with ${team.stageStanding.stage1} but the first outputs nothing.

Comment: I think @Harm Brugge means:
<c:out value="${requestScope[stageStandingTeam]}"></c:out>
and
<c:out value="${team.stageStanding.stage1}"></c:out>

Should both output the same value when param.stage equals 1 and the requestScope line isn't working